# JS. Can I manipulate the DOM in a MutationObserver callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

I am using a `MutationObserver` for cut & paste from Excel into a div. Once pasted I cleanup the inserted HTML with some jQuery hackery.

Is it ok to manipulate the DOM in this way in the `MutationObserver` callback?

Comment: Make sure you don't get into infinite recursion.

Comment: Yep. I'll keep that in mind.